# Setting up Ubuntu 16.04 for NFSv4 access only?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I've been experiencing considerable frustration regarding the state of NFS documentation for a while, but can't find anything written about the following.
I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu 16.04 server system to serve only NFSv4 shares; i.e. disabling NFSv3 and NFSv2.  The primary reason is that I want to shut down the rpcbind service, which is considered a security problem on my campus, but also because there isn't really any reason for NFSv3 any more that I can think of.  I know how to do this on an Arch system, and this link (https://serverfault.com/questions/530908/nfsv4-and-rpcbind/868556#868556) provides hints about what needs to be done on a RedHat/CentOS system, but I can't find any documentation for Ubuntu.  Of course life is further complicated by the fact that systemd does things for you.  I notice that currently nfs-idmapd.service
 and nfs-mountd.service are running.  I stopped the rpcbind service by hand for now, since just installing nfs-server on Ubuntu starts this service for you automatically, but it comes back to life if I restart nfs-server.  Of some considerable concern is this:

```
root@kraken:/etc/default# systemctl list-dependencies nfs-server
nfs-server.service
● ├─auth-rpcgss-module.service
● ├─nfs-config.service
● ├─nfs-idmapd.service
● ├─nfs-mountd.service
● ├─proc-fs-nfsd.mount
● ├─rpc-svcgssd.service
● ├─rpcbind.socket
● ├─system.slice
● └─network.target
```

The serverfault thread above indicates that the following services are unnecessary when using only NFSv4:

rpcgssd, rpcsvcgssd, and of course rpcbind, but these are all dependencies of the nfs-server service.

Thoughts, comments, links to a tutorial or more information?

Comment: Simply block the unwanted open ports with `netfilter` via `iptables`.

Comment: Hi -

Yes, I've been doing that a lot for legacy machines.  I was hoping for a cleaner install.